# Functional categarization of microservices versus Entity based categorization

Tags: architecture, microservices, software-design

I am yet to start working on a project, which involves the usual website authentication and some other services. But this is the first time that I am thinking of splitting the website into micro-services. I am confused on how to split the micro-services,

- By Entities
  meaning a micro-service looks after all customer related functionality, another looks after another entity's functionality and so on.
- By Service
  meaning, one micro-service looks after authentication of user, another microservice looks after another service that a user can do on the website and so on.
  Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microservices should be designed around business capabilities, not horizontal layers such as data access or messaging .

Generally you can take following path

1 ) Start by analyzing the business domain to understand the application's functional requirements. The output of this step is an informal description of the domain, which can be refined into a more formal set of domain models.

2 ) Next, define the bounded contexts of the domain. Each bounded context contains a domain model that represents a particular subdomain of the larger application.

3 ) Within a bounded context, apply tactical DDD patterns to define entities, aggregates, and domain services.

4 ) Use the results from the previous step to identify the microservices in your application.

I have taken the excerpt from Microsoft official website and i think you should definitely read the docs (shared below) to model your microservices.

[How to identify microservices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/model/domain-analysis)